# Categorizing Hastags based on similarities

Tags: twitter, machine-learning, nlp, text-analysis

I have different documents with a list of hashtags in each. I would like to group them under the most relevant hashtag (which would be present in the document itself). 
Egs: If there are #Eco, # Ecofriendly # GoingGreen - I would like to group all these under the most relevant and representative Hashtag (say #Eco). How should I be approaching this and what techniques and algorithms should I be looking at?

Comment: What approaches have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a bipartite graph of documents-hashtags and use clustering on a bipartite graph: 
http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/inderjit/public_papers/kdd_bipartite.pdf

This way I am not using the content of the document, but just clustering the hashtags, which is what you wanted.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not very strict, and as such may have multiple answers, however, if we assume that you literally want "I would like to group all these under the most common Hashtag", then simply loop through all hashtags, compute have often they come up, and then for each document select the one with highest number of occurences.

Something like

```
N = {}
for D in documents:
    for h in D.hashtags:
        if h not in N: N[h] = 0
        N[h] += 1

for D in documents:
    best = None
    for h in D.hashtags:
        if best==None or N[best] < N[h]:
            best = h
    print 'Document ',D,' should be tagged with ',best
```

Comment: I want them to be grouped under the most relevant and representative hashtag in the group

Comment: which is highly unprecise and vague. There are dozens of possible definitions of "relevant and representative", the simplest one is covered in the answer above.